# R: How to read a CSV file having Product ID numeric 15 digits?

Tags: r, csv

While I am reading the data file (*.CSV file), the Product column is read as scientific and hence both the product ID's 102307200002148 and 102307200026812 read as 1.02307e+14. While comparing, it is unable to differentiate:

> stock$Product[14]==stock$Product[15]
>      [1] TRUE

Tried with options(scipen=999) which takes first 6 digits and fill rest with 0s and problem remains. Please help.

Comment: use the `colClasses` argument to `read.csv` to specify that the `Product` column is of type `"character"` (or `"factor"`)

Comment: A double can hold 15 decimal digits; you're seeing a representation and not the whole value.  Try `options(digits=22)`.  However for a product ID, a factor makes more sense.

Comment: With colClasses it is reading as chr "1.02307E+14". No luck.

Comment: @PB4133944 Something else must be wrong.  Perhaps you wrote the file with this format.

Comment: With options(digits=22) it is reading the Id as 102307000000000.0000000. With "factor" it is creating only 6 levels (like "1.02307E+14"...) whereas data has 20 product IDs.

Comment: File is plane and simple csv data file from real world (not created) and I can see the the full product ID while opening in excel (and by defining cell format as text).

Comment: Maybe put your `read.csv` (or `read.table` or whichever you use) line in your question so we can see what's happening?

Comment: please make a reproducible example (if you're worried about confidentiality you can make a trivial CSV file that just contains the product IDs you've already showed us -- make sure that you can replicate your problem with the minimized file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of try, just now I have realized that my csv file was corrupted (perhaps my excel auto saved it, not sure) and changed the value of product ID to scientific notation in data file. After bringing the correct csv file, my code is working as expected without any special coding.

Thanks to all of you for your support and try to fix my problem, I sincerely appreciate.

Comment: It's an extremely annoying "feature" of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

prepare data which was given in question

```
data <- c("102307200002148","102307200026812")
write.csv(data, file = "data.csv")    
read <- read.csv(file = "data.csv")
```

test data

```
> read
  X            x
1 1 1.023072e+14
2 2 1.023072e+14
```

test again reading as character

```
> as.character(read[1,])
[1] "1"               "102307200002148"
```

data is ready for comapring

```
> as.character(read[1,]) == as.character(read[2,])
[1] FALSE FALSE
> as.character(read[1,]) == as.character(read[1,])
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: You're not "reading as character," but rather interpreting the numeric value as a character.  If it had additional digits, this would not work.

Comment: yes, but it gets a +1 for replicating what the OP *said* they have in their file and showing that based on the description, simply reading with `read.csv()` should work.